# trying to build a random password generator (without library random)

Tags: python, list, time

How do I convert the returned remainder into characters from my list?  (trying to build a random password generator)

Here's what I have so far:

```py
import time

seconds = time.time() 
print(seconds)

x = float(7) 
y = seconds 
print(y % x)

savage = (y % x) 
print(str(savage), type(savage))

list = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','!','@','#','$','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
new = str(list).join(str(savage))
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to use the returned remainder from `(x % y)` to print different characters from my list. I'm thinking that a way to convert the returned remainder to characters in my list would be to print a new set of characters each time the program is run since the `seconds` is always changing with time.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your question per se as long as it is a "I'm trying to learn" type of question. However, just in case you intend to use your code in production **don't reinvent the wheel**. Especially with respect to cryptographic code such as generating random values. You are certain to do it wrong or, at best, write a suboptimal solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using the library `random`, here's one way to do it. I've used the number itself to generate an index between 0 and 65, to determine the character in `lis`. However the password length varies between 15 and 18.

```
import time

lis = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','!','@','#','$','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']

#try to generate 10 random passwords:
for _ in range(10):
    y = time.time() 
    # print(y)
    savage = y % 7
    savage = str(savage).replace('.', '')
    # print(savage)

    pw = ''
    n = len(savage)
    for i in range(n):
        if int(savage[i]) <= 5 and i <= 15:    #max idx is 50+15
            idx = int(savage[i])*10 + i
            pw += lis[idx]
        else:
            idx = (int(savage[i])-5)*10 + i
            pw += lis[idx]
    print(n, pw)
```

Output:

```
15 EFQxopKLstYZG@Y
17 EFQxy$qL23O5mHy$K
17 EFQxIJg1MNYPwRIT!
16 EFQHoJUriNEP!xSP
17 EFQHyTUVM3YF!Ro$K
16 EFQHSTABWDOZG@8z
18 EFQHofqriDOFQ@I$qG
16 EFQHoTqViDO5!no$
17 EFQHoJ01iNkl6@Szg
17 EF!dSzghCXOPm@SJA
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm prohibited from using the random library for this project.

Comment: I've updated my answer without using the library random, see if it can meet your purpose

Comment: This makes so makes much more sense than how I was trying to do it. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

This code is more simple to read

```
import time

def generate_password(length):
  password = ""
  characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()-_=+{}[]:;'<>,./?"
  while length > len(characters):
       characters = characters * 2
  x = 1
  for i in range(length):
    index = int(time.time() * 1000) % len(characters)
    if (index < len(characters) and index >= 0):
        x -=1
        index+=x
    char = characters[index]
    password += char
  return password

length = int(input("Enter the length of the password: "))
password = generate_password(length)
print("Your password is:", password)
```